# Grouping not displaying data correctly in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to show data in group using jqGrid. For less entry it is working fine. But as the rows increases. It create multiple group for same name.

This is my jqGrid snippet.

```js
var v = xmlString.XmlToString();
 $("#Addresses").jqGrid({
  datatype: 'xmlstring',
  datastr: v,
  mtype: 'GET',
  
  beforeRequest: function () {
   //alert('beforeRequest');
  },
  loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {
   $(this).HideBusy();
   //   alert(status);
   //     alert(error);
   alert(xhr.responseText);
  },

  loadComplete: function (data) {
   //            var top_rowid = $('#Addresses tr:nth-child(2)').attr('id');
   //            $("#Addresses").setSelection(top_rowid, true);
   $(this).HideBusy();
  },
  ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
  xmlReader: { repeatitems: false, root: "BPAddresses", row: 'row' },
  colNames: ['Address', 'AdresType'],
  colModel: [
     { name: 'AddressName', index: 'AddressName', sortable: false },
     { name: 'AddressType', index: 'AddressType', sortable: false, align: "left", formatter: FormatBPAddress, unformat: UnFormatBPAddress }
      ],
  viewrecords: true,
  gridview: true,
  autowidth: true,
  shrinkToFit: false,
  height: 150,
  width: 110,
  rowNum: 100,
  beforeSelectRow: function (id, e) {
   //set contact person values back to xml
   var Name = $("#Addresses").jqGrid('getCell', id, 'AddressName');
   selectedContactID = Name;
   var addType = $("#Addresses").jqGrid('getCell', id, 'AddressType');
   selectedAddType = addType;
   //debugger;
   $("#gbox_Addresses").block({ message: null });
   return true;
  },
  onSelectRow: function (id) {
   var Address = $("#Addresses").jqGrid('getCell', id, 'AddressName');
   SelectedAddresses.find("BPAddresses>row").each(function (index) {
    if ($(this).find('AddressName').text() == Address) {
     var v1 = $(this).XmlToString();
     var v2 = '<BPAddresses>' + v1 + '</BPAddresses>';
     var $parsedXML = $($.parseXML(v2));
     $(this).SetValuesToControl("BusinessPartner #uxAddresses", $parsedXML, dataMember);
     $("#uxUpdateAdd").removeAttr("disabled");
     $("#uxCancelAdd").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
   });
  },
  grouping: true,
  groupingView: {
   groupField: ['AddressType'],
   groupColumnShow: [false],
   groupCollapse: true,
   plusicon: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-e',
   minusicon: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-s',
   openicon: 'ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e'
  },
  scrollOffset: 0
 }).jqGrid('navGrid', '', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, searchOnEnter: false, search: false }, {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: false });
 

//this is my xml code.
<BPAddresses>
   <row>
    <AddressName>a1</AddressName>
    <Street>a1</Street>
    <Country>IN</Country>
    <AddressType>bo_BillTo</AddressType>
    <StreetNo>a1</StreetNo>
    <BPCode>A2</BPCode>
    <RowNum>0</RowNum>
   </row>
   <row>
    <AddressName>a2</AddressName>
    <Street>a2</Street>
    <Country>IN</Country>
    <AddressType>bo_BillTo</AddressType>
    <StreetNo>a2</StreetNo>
    <BPCode>A2</BPCode>
    <RowNum>1</RowNum>
   </row>
   <row>
    <AddressName>a3</AddressName>
    <Street>a3</Street>
    <Country>IN</Country>
    <AddressType>bo_BillTo</AddressType>
    <StreetNo>a3</StreetNo>
    <BPCode>A2</BPCode>
    <RowNum>2</RowNum>
   </row>
   <row>
    <AddressName>sh1</AddressName>
    <Country>IN</Country>
    <AddressType>bo_ShipTo</AddressType>
    <BPCode>A2</BPCode>
    <RowNum>3</RowNum>
   </row>
   <row>
    <AddressName>sh2</AddressName>
    <Country>IN</Country>
    <AddressType>bo_ShipTo</AddressType>
    <BPCode>A2</BPCode>
    <RowNum>4</RowNum>
   </row>
   <row>
    <AddressName>Define New</AddressName>
    <Street/>
    <Block/>
    <ZipCode/>
    <City/>
    <County/>
    <Country/>
    <State/>
    <BuildingFloorRoom/>
    <AddressType>bo_ShipTo</AddressType>
    <StreetNo/>
    <BPCode/>
    <RowNum/>
    <GlobalLocationNumber/>
   </row>
   <row>
    <AddressName>Define New</AddressName>
    <Street/>
    <Block/>
    <ZipCode/>
    <City/>
    <County/>
    <Country/>
    <State/>
    <BuildingFloorRoom/>
    <AddressType>bo_BillTo</AddressType>
    <StreetNo/>
    <BPCode/>
    <RowNum/>
    <GlobalLocationNumber/>
   </row>
  </BPAddresses>
```

In the above xml there are only two groups viz: Bill To & Ship To.
It is showing 3 group in my grid Bill To, Ship To & one more Bill To.

Can anybody help me in this?

PFA:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use `groupField: ['AddressType']` then the input data have to be sorted by `AddressType`.